# Why does PDF.js render the page upside down occasionally and cause a render on page error in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf.js

I have a strange PDF.js issue when using it within a Vue.js component. It results in the PDF being upside down occasionally. I have seen this issue on Stack Overflow but I am using promises on rendering each page so I don't see how I am rerendering or causing the canvas to be reused other than outside of what Vue components naturally do. The error I am getting is as follows:

> pdf.min.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot use the same canvas during multiple render() operations. Use different canvas or ensure previous operations were cancelled or completed.
> at InternalRenderTask.initializeGraphics (pdf.min.js:22:64667)

```js
Vue.component(
    "embeddedpdf",
    {
        template: `<canvas :id="canvasid" class="the-canvas"></canvas>`,
        props: {
            filedir: {
                type: String,
            },
            canvasid: {
                type: String,
            },
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
                required: false,
            },
            menus: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
                required: false,
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pageNum: 1,
                pageNumPending: null,
                pageRendering: false,
                totalPageCount: null,
                loadingFile: true,
                dialog: false,
                exists: true,
                timeout: false,
            }  
        },
        methods: {
            renderPage(num) {
                pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.15.349/build/pdf.worker.min.js";
                var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.filedir);
                loadingTask.promise.then(
                    this.loadPDF, function (reason) {
                    // PDF loading error
                    console.error(reason);
                });
            },
            loadPDF(pdf) {

                //console.log('PDF loaded');

                // Fetch the first page
                this.pageRendering = true;
                //console.log("number of pages " + pdf.numPages);
                this.totalPageCount = pdf.numPages;

                pdf.getPage(this.pageNum).then(this.loadPage);
            },
            loadPage(page) {
                //console.log('Page loaded');

                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasid);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(this.rendering);
            },
            rendering() {
                //console.log('Page rendered');
                this.pageRendering = false;
                if (this.pageNumPending !== null) {
                    // New page rendering is pending
                    this.renderPage(this.pageNumPending);
                    this.pageNumPending = null;
                }
            },
            queueRenderPage(num) {
                if (this.pageRendering) {
                    this.pageNumPending = num;
                } else {
                    this.renderPage(num);
                }
            },
            onPrevPage() {

                if (this.pageNum <= 1) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum--;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            onNextPage() {
                if (this.pageNum >= this.totalPageCount) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum++;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            async checkFileExist(path, timeout = 30000) {

                let totalTime = 0;
                let checkTime = 3000;
                var self = this;

                return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const timer = setInterval(function () {

                        totalTime += checkTime;

                        if (totalTime <= timeout) {
                            let fileExists = self.fileExist(path);

                            if (fileExists) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                resolve(fileExists);

                            }
                        } else {
                            reject("File not found and pdf loader timed out")
                        }
                    }, checkTime);
                })
            },
            fileExist(urlToFile) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
                xhr.send();

                if (xhr.status == "404") {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            setupFunction() {
                this.timeout = false
                var self = this
                if (this.filedir == null || this.filedir == "") {
                    self.loadingFile = true;
                } else {
                    this.checkFileExist(this.filedir).then(function (response) {
                        self.loadingFile = false;
                        self.renderPage(this.pageNum);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.error("Error: ", error);
                        self.timeout = true;
                    })
                }
            },
            docxLocation(value) {
                if (value == null || value == "") {
                    return ""

                } else {
                    return value.substr(0, value.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".docx"
                }
            },
            resolveYourReview: function() {
                alert('test')
            },
            fullscreenPDF() {
                        window.open(
                            this.filedir,
                            '_blank') // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.setupFunction()
        },
        watch: {
            filedir: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            disabled: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            menuItemsArray: function () {
            }
        }
    }
);

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

```css
.the-canvas {
    width:100%; 
    height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <embeddedpdf
            fileDir="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf"
            canvasid="canvasid"
          />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.15.349/build/pdf.js"></script>
</body>
```

Updated code which does not seem to result in any issues:

```
<template id="embeddedpdf">
    <v-card v-if="disabled == true" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container class="d-flex" fill-height fluid>
            <v-row class="align-center justify-center">
                <v-icon x-large>fas fa-lock</v-icon>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && timeout == true" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-menu bottom
                        right>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn light
                               icon
                               v-bind="attrs"
                               v-on="on">
                            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <template v-for="(item,index) in menus">
                            <v-list-item v-if="item.isActive" :key="index" v-on:click="$emit(item.clickFunction)" link>
                                <v-list-item-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </template>
                        <v-list-item :href="downloadlink" download link>
                            <v-list-item-title>Download</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
            </v-card-title>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && loadingFile == true && timeout == false" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container class="d-flex" fill-height fluid>
            <v-row class="align-center justify-center">
                <v-progress-circular :size="100"
                                     color="secondary"
                                     class="my-16"
                                     indeterminate></v-progress-circular>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && loadingFile == false && timeout == false" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-menu bottom
                        right>

                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn light
                               icon
                               v-bind="attrs"
                               v-on="on">
                            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <template v-for="(item,index) in menus">
                            <v-list-item v-if="item.isActive" :key="index" link>
                                <v-list-item-title v-on:click="$emit(item.clickFunction)">{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </template>
                        <v-list-item :href="downloadlink" download link>
                            <v-list-item-title>Download</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <span>
                    <v-btn light
                           icon
                           @@click="fullscreenPDF()">
                        <v-icon light>mdi-fullscreen</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </span>
            </v-card-title>
            <canvas :id="canvasid" class="the-canvas"></canvas>
            <v-row class="justify-center align-self-end">
                <v-btn class="mx-2"
                       fab
                       dark
                       small
                       color="primary"
                       outlined
                       @@click="onPrevPage">
                    <v-icon dark>
                        mdi-rewind
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn class="mx-2"
                       fab
                       dark
                       small
                       color="primary"
                       outlined
                       @@click="onNextPage">
                    <v-icon dark>
                        mdi-fast-forward
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.component('embeddedpdf',
    {
        template: '#embeddedpdf',
        props: {
            base64string: {
                type: String,
            },
            canvasid: {
                type: String,
            },
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
                required: false,
            },
            menus: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
                required: false,
            },
            downloadlink: {
                type: String,
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pageNum: 1,
                pageNumPending: null,
                pageRendering: false,
                totalPageCount: null,
                loadingFile: true,
                dialog: false,
                exists: true,
                timeout: false,
            }  
        },
        methods: {
            renderPage(num) {
                pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.5.141/pdf.worker.min.js";
                var pdfData = atob(this.base64string);
                var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
                
                loadingTask.promise.then(
                    this.loadPDF, function (reason) {
                    // PDF loading error
                    console.error(reason);
                });
            },
            loadPDF(pdf) {
                //console.log('PDF loaded');
                if (this.pageRendering == false) {
                    // Fetch the first page
                    this.pageRendering = true;
                    //console.log("number of pages " + pdf.numPages);
                    this.totalPageCount = pdf.numPages;

                    pdf.getPage(this.pageNum).then(this.loadPage);
                }
            },
            loadPage(page) {
                //console.log('Page loaded');
                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasid);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(this.rendering);
            },
            rendering() {
                //console.log('Page rendered');
                this.pageRendering = false;
                if (this.pageNumPending != null) {
                    // New page rendering is pending
                    this.renderPage(this.pageNumPending);
                    this.pageNumPending = null;
                }
            },
            queueRenderPage(num) {
                if (this.pageRendering) {
                    this.pageNumPending = num;
                } else {
                    this.renderPage(num);
                }
            },
            onPrevPage() {

                if (this.pageNum <= 1) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum--;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            onNextPage() {
                if (this.pageNum >= this.totalPageCount) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum++;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            async checkFileExist(path, timeout = 50000) {

                let totalTime = 0;
                let checkTime = 2000;
                var self = this;

                return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const timer = setInterval(function () {

                        totalTime += checkTime;

                        if (totalTime <= timeout) {
                            let fileExists = self.fileExist(path);

                            if (fileExists) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                resolve(fileExists);

                            }
                        } else {
                            reject("File not found and pdf loader timed out")
                        }
                    }, checkTime);
                })
            },
            fileExist(urlToFile) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
                xhr.send();

                if (xhr.status == "404") {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            setupFunction() {
                this.timeout = false
                var self = this
                if (this.base64string == null || this.base64string == "") {
                    self.loadingFile = true;
                } else {
                    self.loadingFile = false;
                    if (self.pageRendering == false) {
                        self.renderPage(this.pageNum);
                    }
                }
            },
            resolveYourReview: function() {
                alert('test')
            },
            fullscreenPDF() {

                var base64str = this.base64string;

                // decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
                var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
                var len = binary.length;
                var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
                var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                // create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"               
                var blob = new Blob([view], { type: "application/pdf" });
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(url);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.setupFunction()
        },
        watch: {
            base64string: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            disabled: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            menuItemsArray: function () {
                //this.setupFunction()
            }
        }
     })
</script>
<style scoped>
    .the-canvas {
        width:100%; 
        height: auto; 
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I have not had this issue anymore. Il be honest I cannot remember how i fixed it. I did switch from generating pdfs from libreoffice to using onedrive to convert word documents to pdfs so maybe that fixed it?

Comment: Added an updated code which I do not have issues anymore. Its a full component using pdfjs and vuetify.

Comment: Hello! I attempted to make your code runnable in a Stack Snippet. I've made some assumptions as to what libraries you were using based on existing information in your question (Vue 2.x, Vuetify 2.x, PDF.js 2.15.349), would you be able to verify this assumption? I've also written some setup code to render your component and pass in necessary props, would you be able to verify this is ok? Your question didn't provide a Vue template so I've just provided a `canvas`, please edit so that your original template is in the question too. Thanks!

Comment: Also please do not edit in answers to your question. They should be posted as an answer. See this [reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258378/is-it-good-practice-to-update-your-question-with-the-answer-that-worked) on Meta SO.

Comment: Regarding the issues described in your question, I wasn't able to reproduce them when creating the snippet. If possible, please edit the snippet so that the issue is reproduced.

Comment: I can delete this question. It sat for so long unanswered that I cannot remember how the issue came about other than the libreoffice pdf I would load into the pdf.js plugin above would be upside down at times. Sounds like Dolphin may have had a similar issue. None the less I cannot say the code above fixes the issue except that I have not had that issue. Also your assumptions were correct to the libraries. I can include the cdn links to the libraries i used if that is helpful?